Why the WordPress plugin does not load the JS file with different versions?
To prevent my WordPress plugin from loading a cached version of JavaScript, I added the following codelines:
wp_enqueue_style($this->plugin_name, plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '../css/file-converter.css', array(), time(), 'all');
wp_enqueue_script($this->plugin_name, plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '../js/file-converter.js', array('jquery'), time(), true);

However, when loading the post with the plugin shortcode, such as this one: https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/jpg-to-png/, in Chrome DevTools > NetWork, I will see it always load the JS file with the same version:
file-converter.js?ver=1723442378

Note the ver=1723442378 is NEVER changed.
Below is the screenshot:

I think this is caused by some level of cache software, and my site has the following cache software:
Cloudflare, Nginx, WP Rocket, Redis Object Cache, Asset CleanUp Pro, OpCache

So I disable them one by one. However, after all these cache plugins are disabled. I still see the JS with the same version ver=1723442378 being loaded.
So I am totally frustrated and want to find out the cause that makes the same version being loaded repeatedly?
Update:
I try a different computer and it also load the version 1723442378

try "wp_enqueue_script($this->plugin_name, plugin_dir_url(FILE) . '../js/file-converter.js?v=' . time(), array('jquery'), null, true);" null should force fresh load. Unless server have other cache that is already loading your page in the mention timeframe.
